# Add object to a BindingList in a BindingList

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a bindinglist of activity, and each activity has a bindinglist of BuyOrders

```
bindingListActivty.Select(k => k._dataGridViewId == 1);
```

If I understand correctly, i can select the activity, but I cannot access any method inside the activity. How do I access the method without creating a new instance of a bindinglist ?

I tought this would work, but no

```
bindingListActivty.Select(k => k._dataGridViewId == 1).addBuyOrders(new BuyOrders());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
// Get the activity from bindingListActivity, whose k._dataGridViewId is equal to 1.
var activity = bindingListActivty.SingleOrDefault(k => k._dataGridViewId == 1);

// If the activity has been found and the a new BuyOrders object.
if(activity!=null)
    activity.addBuyOrders(new BuyOrders());
```

Answer (score 5):

Select returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which will not have your `addBuyOrders` method. You need to either use a `foreach` or you could use `FirstOrDefault` with a `Where` clause to get the individual object that exposes the method.

For example:

foreach:

```
var activities = bindingListActivty.Select(k => k._dataGridViewId == 1);
foreach(var a in activities)
{
    a.addBuyOrders(new BuyOrders());
}
```

FirstOrDefault (this likely makes more sense based on your where clause):

```
var activity = bindingListActivty.Where(k => k._dataGridViewId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
if (activity != null)
{
    activity.addBuyOrders(new BuyOrders());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important for you to understand that `IEnumerable<T>.Select()` is not for querying. You need to use Where(), First() or FirstOrDefault() for any queries. Select() is a **projection** of each element. This means you are performing a transformation from T1 -> T2. You have made a projection of each *activity* on a *boolean* value (`k._dataGridViewId == 1`). The result type of

```
bindingListActivty.Select(k => k._dataGridViewId == 1);
```

is

```
IEnumerable<bool>
```